# Creating an object from a base class object in Python

Tags: python

I have a base class:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, food=None):
        self.name = name
        self.food = food

    def eat(self):
        print "The %s eats some %s" % (self.name, self.food)
```

And a class that extends it:

```
class Pet(Animal):
    def pet(self):
        print "You pet the %s." % self.name
    def feed(self):
        print "You put some %s into the bowl." % self.food
        self.eat()
```

Let's say I have an `Animal` object, created thusly:

```
>>> fluffy_as_animal = Animal('dog', 'kibbles')
```

Is there a straightforward way in python to create a `Pet` object from `fluffy_as_animal`, short of actually writing out:

```
>>>> fluffy_as_pet = Pet(fluffy_as_animal.name, fluffy_as_animal.food)
```

## Update

The reason I'm doing this implementation is that I have a class with a function that returns a set of objects of type `Animal` all which I want to actually use as `Pet` objects:

```
class AnimalStore(object):
    def fetch(count, query=None, server=None, *args, **kwargs):
        connection = connect_to_server(server)
        resp = connection.fetch_animals(query)
        objects = parse_response(resp)
        animals = []
        for a in objects[:count]:
            animals.append(Animal(a['name'], a.['food']))
        return animals

class PetStore(AnimalStore):
    def fetch(count, query=None, server=None, *args, **kwargs):
        query = 'type=pet AND %s' % query
        animals = super(PetFactory, self).fetch(count, query, server, *args, **kwargs)
        pets = []
        for animal in animals:
            pets.append(magic_function(animal))
        return pets
```

`AnimalStore` and `PetStore` are in separate modules. `AnimalStore` is part of a standard `Animal` API and doesn't change. Basically I want to extend the `Animal` API by fetching a list of pets using the same mechanism used for animals, and I want to be able to take advantage of all of the other built-in functions that the Animal API already provides for its `Animal` and `AnimalStore` classes.

Comment: Don't Do That.  That's simply a bad way to do OO programming.  Why can't you simply create the `Pet` from the beginning?  Or.  Why aren't you using Delegation between Animal (the object) and it's role as a Pet?

Comment: Delegation is probably the answer! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Notice the super(PetFactory, self) in PetStore's fetch(). Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using delegation (credit should go to [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516263/creating-an-object-from-a-base-class-object-in-python/5622011#comment-6264122)):

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, food=None):
        self.name = name
        self.food = food

    def eat(self):
        print "The %s eats some %s" % (self.name, self.food)

class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, animal=None):
        self.animal = animal

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.animal, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        return setattr(self.animal, key, value)

    def eat(self):
        return self.animal.eat()

    def pet(self):
        print "You pet the %s." % self.name

    def feed(self):
        print "You put some %s into the bowl." % self.food
        self.eat()
```

I only hope I implemented it correctly; either way, it works!

Answer (score 4):

You can write the `__init__()` for `Pet` to accept an instance of `Animal` (or really, any ojbect with the necessary attributes -- duck typing!) as well as the individual attributes. Then you could just do `fluffy_as_pet = Pet(fluffy_as_animal)`. Or provide a class method (e.g. `Pet.from_object()`) to do the same, if you don't want to overload `__init__()`. Even if you don't control the `Animal` and `Pet` classes, you could make your own subclasses of them that behave as you need.

However, it would be best to go a step further and simply don't write code that accepts `Animal` but not `Pet`. Then you don't have to convert it. Again, duck typing -- if an object has the right attributes, you can use it regardless of its type.

Comment: I would like to state that duck typing is my favorite and least favorite thing about Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
fluffy_as_pet = object.__new__(Pet)
fluffy_as_pet.__dict__ = fluffy_as_animal.__dict__.copy()
```

or

```
from copy import copy
fluffy_as_pet = copy(fluffy_as_animal)
fluffy_as_pet.__class__ = Pet
```

but both those ways are probably more of a hack than a clean solution.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would use a classmethod for this:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def fetch(cls, name):
        # DB code left out intentionally.
        return cls(name)


class Dog(Animal):
    def bark(self):
        print("woof")
```

That way calling `Dog().get('fido')` will return an object of type `Dog` and `Animal().get('Mickey')` will return an object of type `Animal`.