# Cast an object to a derived type in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I want to cast an object of type A to type B so I can use B's methods. Type B inherits A. For example I have class my class B:

```
class B(A):
    def hello(self):
        print('Hello, I am an object of type B')
```

My Library, Foo, has a function that returns an object of type A, which I want to cast to type B.

```
>>>import Foo
>>>a_thing = Foo.getAThing()
>>>type(a_thing)
A
>>># Somehow cast a_thing to type B
>>>a_thing.hello()
Hello, I am an object of type B
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this does not exist in Python.  You should write a function that takes an object of type A, and returns an object of type B by, for example, copying attributes of the type A object to a new type B object.

Comment: I saw the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663630/object-type-casting-in-python-design-suggestion) but I was hoping for something more Pythonic.

Comment: Do you have any real use cases for this. getAThing of your code is returning object of class A, and how do you think it can be cast to class B.

Comment: I think in Java it would look something like this: B a_thing = (B) Foo.getAThing();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no subclassing in Python. What you can do is creating another object and copy all attributes.  Your B class constructor should take an argument of type A in order to copy all attributes:

```
class B(A):
  def __init__(self, other):
    # Copy attributes only if other is of good type
    if isintance(other, A):
      self.__dict__  = other.__dict__.copy()
  def hello(self):
    print('Hello, I am an object of type B')
```

Then you can write:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.hello()
Hello, I am an object of type A
>>> a = B(a)
>>> a.hello()
Hello, I am an object of type B
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to write a class method for B that takes an A object and creates a new B object using the information from it.

```
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def from_A(cls, A_obj):
       value = A.value
       other_value = A.other_value
       return B(value, other_value)

a_thing = B.from_A(a_thing)
```

Comment: Additionally, if you used `classmethod` you can(maybe should?) use the `cls` object to init the returned object: `return cls(value, other_value)` this way if class C will inherit from B and the user call `C.from_a(...)` it will return C and not B.