# Subclass a complicated object, and init an instance from its parents class

Tags: python, datetime, subclass

In the following example `Foo` class (trying to make a `datetime` class that has extra methods). I also would like to be able to chain method calls (e.g. `foo.bar().baz()`), as well as be able to pass the object to existing function which expects a `datetime` object.

When instantiating it I get a `TypeError` as shown below:

```
from pytz import UTC
from datetime import datetime

class Foo(datetime):
    def bar(self, timezone):
        print(self.astimezone(timezone))            
        return self

now = datetime.now(UTC)
Foo(now) # TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

I am guessing the error is coming from trying to make a `datetime` object from a `datetime` object. My question is very similar to this post [Creating an object from a base class object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516263/creating-an-object-from-a-base-class-object-in-python). i.e. How does one initiate a child class from a parent object.
I tried the delegation solution in the post but it resulted in recursion and some messy code. I am thinking there must be a better way!

Comment: Essentially you're trying to do `datetime(datetime.now())`, which also wouldn't work. `Foo.now()` would probably do what you want…

Comment: What do you expect ``Foo(now)`` to do?

Comment: Foo.now() is not what I want thanks. I would like to instantiate a Foo object from an existing datetime object, but don't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

You're inheriting the entire behaviour of the `datetime` class. The constructor behaves the same way as the `datetime` constructor, meaning it expects integers for year, month, day and so on. `datetime(datetime.now())` would fail the same way for the same reason.

You can simply use `Foo.now()` to construct a `Foo` instance using the `datetime.now()` mechanics.

If you want to "augment" an existing `datetime` object to a `Foo` object, you should probably add a class method for that:

```
class Foo(datetime):
    @classmethod
    def from_datetime(cls, dt):
        return cls.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp(), dt.tzinfo)
```

Converting the existing `datetime` object to a timestamp and using the `fromtimestamp` constructor here is probably the simplest way to copy over all the needed information. Use like:

```
foo = Foo.from_datetime(now)
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise it was Foo.from_datetime(now), and not Foo(now). I am reading up on __new__ to maybe get it to work.

Comment: If you want `Foo(now)` to work, you simply override `__init__` to accept a `datetime` object. Something like `def __init__(self, dt): super().__init__(dt.year, dt.month, ...)`. Though I'm not sure I'd recommend that necessarily over the alternative classmethod constructor.

Comment: From my testing one cant just add it in __init__, you get an error generated from the super's __new__ before it reaches Foo.__init__

Comment: You're right, it might not be possible to override `__init__` of some builtins. Another reason to simply preserve it and go for the classmethod instead.